# Tag pages not rendering properly

Tags: support, tags, browser

The tag pages are not rendering the list of questions when using Firefox 4.0b8pre or Opera 11.00 alpha build 1029. It does render properly with Google Chrome 8.0.552.5 dev.

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you're on the "FEATURED" tab which, from our current featured list of questions, there are none. Try clicking on "Newest" or another tab instead to get the full question list.

Comment: Yes, you can see in the screenshot it says "0 questions tagged"

Comment: Oh, I see thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add ***?sort=newest&pagesize=15***

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was accessing the tags with this url:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox
```

Which uses the last selected filter.

Adding the following to the url, fixed the problem and make it open the newest tags as I wanted:

```
?sort=newest&pagesize=15
```